# How to make scoreboard show teams instead of players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make it to where points for teams are shown in the scoreboard but I can only manage to get player names on there, what command do I use? On 1.16

Comment: Interesting, this was not asked before. There are a bunch of related questions, but not really this.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need a second scoreboard. Let's say that `single_scores` is the scoreboard that you already have. I'll call the shared one `team_scores`:

```
/scoreboard objectives add team_scores dummy "Insert display name here"
```

Now whenever you want to update the scores, you need to first reset them:

```
/scoreboard players reset * team_scores
```

And now add all team scores to the correct dummy players per team:

```
/scoreboard players operation blue team_scores += @e[team=blue] single_scores
/scoreboard players operation green team_scores += @e[team=green] single_scores
/scoreboard players operation yellow team_scores += @e[team=yellow] single_scores
…
```

This way the sum of the blue team appears as "`blue`" in the sidebar, if you set it to display `team_scores` instead of `single_scores`. You can even give both the same display name if you want to pretend that they're the same.